# Can't add new Scripts to Objects in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to add a script to a GameObject in the Hierarchy View in Unity. I dragged it before to my Scripts-Folder. I got the following message:

> *Can't add script behaviour AssemblyInfo.cs. The script needs to derive from MonoBahaviour!*

I tested it with a new standard script - (Maybe copy and paste would bypass the problem) but also the new standard script gives me the message:

> *No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the filename.*

I looked it already up and the following solutions don't apply to this case.

- The Script name is named exactly like the Monobehaviour Class
- Script Class inherits from the Monobehaviour Class
- There are no typos. (Class name doesn't contain spaces)
- I closed and reopend Unity
- Reset doesn't appear to work

You can check both scripts (which are basically the same) below:

[image: Screenshot of Inspector 1]

[image: Screenshot of Inspector 2]

I use Windows 10 Version 1909 and Unity 2018.4.10f as well a Coding on Visual Studio Code.

Maybe you know what's going on.
Thanks

[Edit] 
There have been some error messages in the Console.

`Generating diff of this object for undo because the type tree changed.This happens if you have used Undo.RecordObject when changing the script property. Please use Undo.RegisterCompleteObjectUndo`

`OnGUIDepth changed: was 0 is 3. Event type was 0`

Comment: You might try deleting the .sln and .csproj for the Unity project. That should cause Unity to regenerate them. The `AssemblyInfo.cs` error is weird; that's autogenerated for every .csproj. I haven't tried this with VS Code (only Visual Studio), though, so you may not have the sln and csproj. :/

Comment: Indeed there have been .sln and the .csproj files. Unity does generate them as also mentioned in this Unity tutorial:
[link](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/project-architecture-unity-project-folder-structure#)
I deleted them, there was no immediate improvement. But after Unity crashed once it worked. I will try to give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a very good answer because I can't deliberately reproduce the answer as well I can't reproduce the problem. But now I again can add scripts to GameObjects in the Hierarchy View.

As in the following Link of a Unity tutorial about: [*Unity Project Folder Structure*](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/project-architecture-unity-project-folder-structure#) there exist the *Visual Studio Solution File*: `.sln` which contains information of the project enviroment and project state. Futhermore there is the *Visual Studio C# Project File*: `.csproj`as which contains project settings and references to files used by the project.

Infos are from https://fileinfo.com/extension/sln and https://fileinfo.com/extension/csproj

I deleted them. (Don't worry Unity autogenerates them.)

Nevertheless there was no immediate improvement. I deleted all script files and tried to drag and drop a new script file. Upon this action Unity crashed. After restarting Unity scripts could be created which worked again - or should I say Unity worked again because there was never a problem with the scripts.

I know, it's a botched solution but if this problem occurs to you and you tried all the bullet points in the question, (a) deleting `.sln` and `.csproj` files, (b) restarting Unity and (c) importing/creating new scripts might work.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Glad you got it to work.